# Recursion: I don't understand why the code will print out n integers 1,2,3,4,5

Tags: java, recursion

My expected result was that is not going to print anything

In the example below if I try to read the code xMethod(5)
as it is a recursive function when =0 i.e. xMethod(0)  I was expecting that it should not get into the if statement.

My expectation for this code was that there should not be an output since the print statement is after the recursive method

```
public class recursionThree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        xMethod(5);
    }

    public static void xMethod(int n){
        if (n > 0){
            xMethod(n-1);
            System.out.print(n + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you understand recursion, then you don't have to read the next sentence. Please read this comment from the beginning. Are you reading this? Why are you reading this? Did you not start-over? Brother Maynard - bring out the holy hand grenade

Comment: The print statement if after the recursive call, but the recursive call will eventually finish (unless you programmed a stack overflow) and then the print is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods don't just get called and not return. They *return* to the caller.

As you may know, methods, when called, are pushed onto a call stack. So when you call `xMethod(5)`, it calls `xMethod(4)`, and *that* calls `xMethod(3)`... creating a call stack like this:

```
xMethod(0)
xMethod(1)
xMethod(2)
xMethod(3)
xMethod(4)
xMethod(5)
main
```

Now what does `xMethod(0)` do? It does not go into the if statement so it returns immediately. When a method returns, *it is popped from the call stack*, and control is back at the next thing in the stack. Now we have:

```
xMethod(1)
xMethod(2)
xMethod(3)
xMethod(4)
xMethod(5)
main
```

Remember we are still at the `xMethod(n-1);` line in the `xMethod(1)` stack frame? Since `xMethod(n-1)` returned, we can continue to run the rest of the code. Therefore, `System.out.print` is called with `n` being `1` (we are still in the `xMethod(1)` stack frame!).

Now `xMethod(1)` finishes running and returns and is popped from the stack. Control is back at `xMethod(2)`. And the cycle continues on, until `xMethod(5)` returns.

Answer (score 2):

You need to step through the program:

- Calling `xMethod(5)` from `main`

  - `n > 0`, so it calls `xMethod(4)`

    - `n > 0`, so it calls `xMethod(3)`

      - `n > 0`, so it calls `xMethod(2)`

        - `n > 0`, so it calls `xMethod(1)`

          - `n > 0`, so it calls `xMethod(0)`

            - n not `> 0`, so it returns without doing anything
          - It prints "1"
        - It prints "2"
      - It prints "3"
    - It prints "4"
  - It prints "5"
  - Done.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple actually.

If we call some function within another function then control returns back to same function once the called function completes it's execution.

In your case as n == 0 the called function returns control back to calling function hence printing 1,2,3,4,5.

Answer (score 0):

in your code, the stack will generate 5 frame for these 5 recursive calls of xMethod. Before each call finished, System.out.print(n + " ") can print the variable n in the frame. your memory stack looks like this

```
 ---------
|   n=1   |
 ---------
|   n=2   |
 ---------
|   n=3   |
 ---------
|   n=4   |
 ---------
|   n=5   |
 ---------
```

every box is a frame, and each frame will be cleaned from top to bottom, so the output would be 1 2 3 4 5

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand recursion is to regard the recursive calls as black box doing what they are supposed to do.

So your `xMethod` prints the numbers 1 to n. It does this, by first printing the numbers 1 to n-1 (using the recursive call) and then printing the number n.